# should I treated the let's encrypt fullchain.pem as a public key

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, terminology, google-cloud-platform

I am using let's encrypt to generate a certificate. It contains 'fullchain.pem' and 'privkey.pem'. should I treated the let's encrypt fullchain.pem as a public key? I find the public key certificate format as same with the `fullchain.pem`.  When the google cloud ask me to upload the public key to bind with the domain, I upload the `fullchain.pem` as the public key block and worked. I did not understand why it works because I always not treated the `fullchain.pem` as a public key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full chain does indeed *contain* the public key. However, containing the public key is not the same thing as being identical.

Laymen often confuse the term with certificate though, and a certificate chain is just one step away from it. PGP also talks about a "public key" while that public key is really a certificate - it contains metadata and may be signed. Your chain just contains the leaf certificate and those certificates required to perform *path validation*, which is the creation of the path of certificates to a trusted root. The root CA and intermediate CA certificates may not be present at Google, so it makes sense to upload those as well.

The `fullchain.pem` will only contain public certificates (starting with your leaf certificate), so it is definitely *public*. Of course, just like with your trust store, you want to maintain the integrity and availability of it though - so some security is still involved.